# Autodesk Inventor API with Python

Tags: python, api, autodesk, autodesk-inventor

I try to use Python for Autodesk Inventor API. For example, I try to make a new sketch in an Inventor part document that I make with Python.

But I have a problem with adding sketches. All of my tries were wrong.
Here's an example of code (one of a lot):

```
import win32com.client

from win32com.client import constants


invApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Inventor.Application")
invApp.Visible = True

asd = invApp.Documents.Add(constants.kPartDocumentObject,"",True)

nsk = asd.PartDocuments.ComponentDefinition.Sketches.Add()
```

There is an error:

```
AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.Autodesk Inventor Object Library.Document instance at 0x284773312>' object has no attribute 'PartDocuments'
```

I tried to find the right way to call the attributes but I have not had any success.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned. Documents.Add() returns a Document object. We need to cast it to a partDocument like this.

```
invDoc = invApp.Documents.Add(constants.kPartDocumentObject,"",True)
invPartDoc = win32com.client.CastTo(invDoc, 'PartDocument')
xyPlane = invPartDoc.ComponentDefinition.WorkPlanes.Item(3)
sketch = invPartDoc.ComponentDefinition.Sketches.Add(xyPlane)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert on Python... but the Documents.Add method return the new document, therefore the asd should contain the PartDocument type

```
asd = invApp.Documents.Add(constants.kPartDocumentObject,"",True)
nsk = asd.ComponentDefinition.Sketches.Add()
```

Comment: thanks. I tried like this, but there is the same mistake: object has no attribute 'ComponentDefinition'.

Comment: I think it also can be incorrect work of module "win32com.client"

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question and I'm not sure what the solution is in Python, but I know what the problem is.  The `Documents.Add` method is typed to return a `Document` object.  The `Document` object does **not** support the `ComponentDefinition` property.  However, in reality, a specific type of document is being returned.  In this case, a `PartDocument` object is actually being returned and it does support the `ComponentDefinition` object.  I don't know how you would cast a variable in Python so it knows it is really a `PartDocument` and not the base class `Document` object.